# Необязательный пробел. Как добавить?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
var pattern = /^[a-z0-9-А-Яа-я]+$/i;
```

Вот мое регулярное выражение, которое пропускает русские и английские буквы и цифры.

Собственно вопрос: как добавить в RegExp **необязательный** пробел в конце и в начале?

```
input1.oninput = function(value) {
    var newValye = this.value;
    if(pattern.test(newValye)){
        bab_number.style.display= "none"
    }else{
        bab_number.style.display= "block"
    }
};
```

Что я хочу?

Я хочу, чтобы при вводе в строку поиска можно было ввести 2-3 слова через пробел.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Один необязательный пробел —  `?` или `\s?`.

Несколько необязательных пробелов —  `*` или `\s*`.

Добавьте в свой шаблон следующим образом:

```
var pattern = /^\s*[a-z0-9-а-яё]+\s*$/i;
```

Чтобы ввести 2-3 слова, нужно использовать

```
var pattern = /^\s*[a-z0-9-а-яё]+(?:\s+[a-z0-9-а-яё]+){1,2}\s*$/i;
```

Я добавил `ё` в выражение и удалил ненужные `А-Я` (так как имеется флаг `i`).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `[a-z0-9-а-яё]+` - 1 и более букв, цифр и `-`
- `(?:\s+[a-z0-9-а-яё]+){1,2}` - 1 или 2 повтора
- `\s+` - 1 и более пробельных символов

  - `[a-z0-9-а-яё]+` - 1 и более букв, цифр и `-`
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `$` - конец строки.