# Регулярное выражение для удаления атрибута

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно регулярное выражение, которое удаляет из строки атрибут `style` со всем содержимым. Помогите подправить, чтобы работало даже при наличии пробелов перед и после знака `=`.

```
str.replace(/style=([\"\'])([^\"\']+)\1/, '')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/95s6qh8u/

Comment: [`/\sstyle\s*=\s*["'][^"']+["']/`](https://regex101.com/r/zyoUey/1)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Необязательный пробел. Как добавить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907080/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: @Эдуард, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ну например вот: `style\s?=\s?(['"]).*?\1`

https://regex101.com/r/CSaDtf/1